# Creating arbitary Higher Kinded Types in Scala

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

Right from the start I'm not absolutely sure I have the right approach to solving my issue. I'm looking for two different answers here:

1. Alternative ideas to the problem are welcomed, but also,
2. I'd like to understand how can I make the example below work - or what is it that I'm missing about higher kinded types that means the approach is wrong?

I have "things" that I wish to dynamically (eventually at run-time) add different attributes to. For example
a "Document" thing may have an Address attribute. Another "Document" thing may
have an "To eMail Address" attribute. A third "Document" thing may have both attributes.

The code below shows Contained (which may represent various things) and a Thing (which is one of those).

It also includes two HigherKindedType traits, which are the attributes I wish to dynamically add to the Contained things.

I can't create a type of "arbitrary type with attribute", which I was hoping to do in the ContainedOps class.

Please help me complete the ??? parts.

```
package example

import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Contained[A]
case class Thing(id: String) extends Contained[Thing]

//case class Attribute(value: String) // needed ?

trait WithAttribute[F[_]] {
  def attribute[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B) : F[B]
}

trait WithAnotherAttribute[F[_]] {
  def anotherAttribute[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B) : F[B]
}

object Contained {

  implicit class ContainedOps[A](c: Contained[A]) {

    type AWithAttribute = A with WithAttribute[Contained]
    def withAttribute(value: String): AWithAttribute = ???

    type AWithAnotherAttribute = A with WithAnotherAttribute[Contained]
    def withAnotherAttribute(value: String): AWithAnotherAttribute = ???

  }

}

object Example extends App {

  val thing = Thing("one")
  println(s"thing: $thing")

  val thingWithAttribute = thing.withAttribute("attributeValue")
  println(s"thingWithAttribute: $thingWithAttribute")

  val thingWithAnotherAttribute = thing.withAnotherAttribute("anotherAttributeValue")
  println(s"thingWithAnotherAttribute: $thingWithAnotherAttribute")

  val thingWithAttributeWithAnotherAttribute = thingWithAttribute.withAnotherAttribute("anotherAttributeValue")
  println(s"thingWithAttributeWithAnotherAttribute: $thingWithAttributeWithAnotherAttribute")

}
```

Comment: You can not really mix dynamic structures with compile time guarantees. Either rethinking your problem to make everything available on compile time. Or use runtime data structures, for example in this case, why not simple use a `Map[String, String]` for your attributes.

Comment: Thanks Luis. One of the options I've considered is similar to your proposal, but using HMap, as the values can be different types (e.g. 'Address', 'EMailAddress'), but that didn't quite suit some of my attribute types. Some attributes (for example) may only be 'added' if the underlying Container[A] is of a particular type.
There's something about HKT that hasn't clicked for me - as I don't understand /why/ the above approach didn't (or can't) work...
I think you're right about the dynamic / static mix but I don't want to "rule it out" until I understand better why I have too.
Thanks again.

Comment: Apologies if I sound rude _(I have the impression my English sounds rude, as it is not my native language)_. But what has **HKT** to do with your problem? A **HKT**, is not more than a type which is parametric on a type constructor _(I also do not see why you need it on your code)_. Also, again an `HMap` does only make sense on compile time, I think your problem is not as dynamic as you think, because you have proper & **static** rules of what are the attributes and which rules dictate their behavior. Maybe you should reformulate this question _(or open a new one)_ only focused on the design.

Comment: Hi Luis - nothing rude about your comments - I welcome them. My "dynamic" comment comes from the fact that a user (at runtime) can choose which attributes get added to the "thing". The attributes available to the user though are always from the same 'set' - so the compile-time solution could be static.
HKT may not be the solution to the underlying problem (as I'd stated originally)...
However - if I present a user a "Document" then they add an "EMail" attribute the 'type' of the document they are now dealing with is "DocumentWithEMail". I'm "playing" with HKT to see if it helps the solution.

Comment: ... and I don't understand them well enough to judge if they do or don't help. (It's a "academic" exercise).

Comment: Usually for this kind of problems, it helps to think how would you use those types / classes. Especially since things will come in runtime, you need to handle them in runtime too, thus usually a very complex solution is not worth. For example, in this case, wouldn't be easier to have all fields in your case class, but wrapped in a option?

Comment: I mean, there are ways to differentiate _(with the type system)_ a Document from a Document with email. But usually this makes sense if you can forbid at compile time passing a document without email when you need one. But, since the data will come from runtime, then you do not win to much in having complex types _(especially because types do not at runtime)_. However, you may want to give a look to [**refined**](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) that is a sweet spot between compile time guarantees and runtime data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198151/discussion-between-nigel-eke-and-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez).

Comment: Based on what you are describing, I agree with Luis that you should just use Option for the attributes you are not sure about. Use a case class with some parameters as Option of types. I hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Scala types are defined at compile time and are static at run time, so "Dynamically creating [] types" is a non-starter.

Comment: My "dynamic" comment comes from the fact that a user (at runtime) can choose which attributes get added to the "thing". The attributes available to the user though are always from the same 'set' - so the compile-time solution could be static.

Comment: If your question is about dynamically adding attributes to an object then that should really be the title of the questions. I have answered the question in the title because that is what other people will expect when they are browsing through the list of questions.